# Como expor o wordpress para acesso externo no Azure / IIS?

Tags: wordpress, servidor, microsoft-azure, dns

Tenho um site feito em wordpress ele está hospedado em um servidor cloud com o seguinte caminho:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site.com.br
```

Para acessar ele localmente com o IP externo eu uso assim:
http://188.93.xxx.xxx:83/site.com.br/

Se eu acessar este endereço de fora do servidor o site não abre.

Dentro do IIS eu tenho a configuração do site

```
Nome: site
caminho físico C:/caminho
tipo de enlace = http
endereço da máquina = 188.93.xxx.xxx
porta = 80
nome do anfitrião =  www.site.com.br
```

Quando eu tento abri o site o mesmo não abre. Tenho outros sites na mesma máquina que funcionam, só com wordpress não funciona. Como posso expor o site?

Comment: Olá Itasouzem reparei que você está tentando usar uma stack `XAMPP`, por curiosidade, você chegou a tentar o [template da galeria do Wordpress](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/wordpress/wordpress/)? Esse caminho é geralmente menos "doloroso" . Também posso recomendar a [distribuição da Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/cloud/azure) se você se sentir confortável em rodar o Ubuntu no Azure.

Comment: Vc subiu uma VM no Azure com Windows Server e está tentando expor sua aplicação web? É isso?

Comment: sim, mais já conseguir

Comment: @itasouza responde vc mesmo sua pergunta, assim outros que tiverem o mesmo problema podem ter ajuda, por gentileza.